# Is it possible to use typed streams in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

In TypeScript, if using the typings [@types/node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node), streams just use `any` as type. This basically works, but is not optimal, since typically what is emitted using the `data` event is always of the same type, especially when using streams with object mode.

Basically, this issue could be solved in a very simple way if streams were using generics, so that you could e.g. say:

```
const passThrough = new PassThrough<Customer>({ objectMode: true });
```

Unfortunately, the above mentioned typings do not support this. I have also found that there is the [ts-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-stream) package, which solves this in a great way – but which does not provide 100% compatibility to the Node.js streams. E.g., async iterators and the `destroy` function are missing.

Given that I do not want to create the typings from scratch, what is my best option to get standard Node.js streams, but strongly typed? Is there any "trick" one can do?

To put it more generically (haha): Is there an established and reasonable way to add generics to an already existing type, that basically uses any?

Comment: Could you add concrete example of type to be augmented and the desired outcome?

Comment: As said instead of `PassThrough`, I would like to be able to use `PassThrough<T>`, which then emits objects of type `T` in a type-safe way instead of emitting data of type `any`.

Comment: *"Given that I do not want to create the typings from scratch"* you could start of with the existing typings [stream.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/v11/stream.d.ts) and start just replace `chunk: any` with `chunk: T` and append `<T = any>` to the interfaces and classes in that file; and `<T>` where they are used. This should be a 5-minute String replacement job. From there on, its based on wether Typescript is OK with the changes or wether something bugs it about them. sry can't check myself on this computer right now.

Comment: Unbelievable that the typed stream is missing in Node.js for the past years. I hope there will be someone who can add this `<T>` to all streams.

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea but not suitable for comments:

[From](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/7590b34f8f428d921fc6624da3c64bb392d3fa04/types/node/stream.d.ts#L254):

```
    type TransformCallback = (error?: Error | null, data?: any) => void;

    interface TransformOptions extends DuplexOptions {
        read?(this: Transform, size: number): void;
        write?(this: Transform, chunk: any, encoding: string, callback: (error?: Error | null) => void): void;
        writev?(this: Transform, chunks: Array<{ chunk: any, encoding: string }>, callback: (error?: Error | null) => void): void;
        final?(this: Transform, callback: (error?: Error | null) => void): void;
        destroy?(this: Transform, error: Error | null, callback: (error: Error | null) => void): void;
        transform?(this: Transform, chunk: any, encoding: string, callback: TransformCallback): void;
        flush?(this: Transform, callback: TransformCallback): void;
    }

    class Transform extends Duplex {
        constructor(opts?: TransformOptions);
        _transform(chunk: any, encoding: string, callback: TransformCallback): void;
        _flush(callback: TransformCallback): void;
    }

    class PassThrough extends Transform { }
```

Just rewrite with your specification - hard to tell without example:

```
    class YourPassThrough<T> extends Duplex {
        constructor(opts?: TransformOptions & { objectMode: true });
        // fit the types
    }
```

But most times it is simpler to just typecast `any` into `T` at usage

```
.on('data', (chunk: T) => {
     //if(!validType(chunk, 'T')) throw TypeError;
});
```